# Battery For Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, battery

Does anyone know of a recommended battery or power bank for the Raspberry Pi 3? I would like to be able to bring my Pi 3 along with me. I know that the Pi 3 gobbles power very fast but I want something that stores power enough for a decent amount of time. I also want something that is a little slim and not enormous and chunky allowing me to carry the battery and the Pi with ease. Does anyone have suggestions on different batteries for me?

Comment: You don't say what a "decent amount of time" is - and you don't say what's running off your Pi - do you have WiFi, Bluetooth running - are you using USB devices? I find a 10000mAh device works fine for me for at least an hour and probably more - but depends on your usage

Comment: Thinking maybe more than an hour i dont know whats reasonable to ask

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use any cheap battery powerbank for charging mobilephones. I suggest you to use some powerbank caapble of supplying at least 15000 mAH or more. But if you draw too little current out of them (100 mA or less) the baattery pack may go to sleep mode. Cutting of supplying power to your raspberry. To prevent this there's a little circuit here:
http://www.dorkbotpdx.org/blog/paul/battery_pack_load

Comment: I don't think there's a chance of the battery pack going to sleep mode while powering an RPi3! Also, I would certainly avoid *cheap* powerbanks which don't provide enough current.

Answer (score 0):

"Decent" amount of time is too open of a request. I have a system with a Pi 4 + 7" HDMI display and a small miliohmmeter circuit that lasts for at least two hours on 6s 21700 Lipo (2 in parallel with 3 in series), using this BMS management system: https://pt.aliexpress.com/item/32783727347.html .

It is though "enormous and chuncky" as you said.